# How to turn an object with keys as indexes into an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to convert an object with indexes as keys, into an array in JavaScript.

For example:

Input: `obj ={1: 'banana', 2: 'apple',3:'orange' }`

Output: `['orange','apple','banana' ]`

I have tried with 'Array.prototype.reverse.apply(obj)', but not able to get the result.

```
 var obj ={1: 'banana', 2: 'apple',3:'orange' };
 var res =Array.prototype.reverse.apply(obj);
 console.log(res); // return the same object, not reverse
```

What are the other usages of Array.prototype.reverse()?

Comment: objects don't have any order.

Comment: You should be using an array if you want order

Comment: Think of it this way if it helps: javascript objects are like blobs and arrays are like straight lines. You just told a blob to turn around 180 degrees

Comment: Thank You! I was trying to use Array.prototype.reverse.apply(obj). But now I got it. I can use it inside the function, and it will return reverse object values.

Comment: I disagree with the closure. The order is given by the keys, which are array indices.

Comment: @DanielA.White I can receive a JS object response where the keys are in a specific order which represent items on the page. It seems to me as though Js objects can definitely have an order.

Answer (score 29):

You can first convert your almost-array-like object to a real array, and then use `.reverse()`:

```
Object.assign([], {1:'banana', 2:'apple', 3:'orange'}).reverse();
// [ "orange", "apple", "banana", <1 empty slot> ]
```

The empty slot at the end if cause because your first index is `1` instead of `0`. You can remove the empty slot with `.length--` or `.pop()`.

Alternatively, if you want to borrow `.reverse` and call it on the same object, it must be a fully-array-like object. That is, it needs a `length` property:

```
Array.prototype.reverse.call({1:'banana', 2:'apple', 3:'orange', length:4});
// {0:"orange", 1:"apple", 3:"banana", length:4}
```

Note it will return the same fully-array-like object object, so it won't be a real array. You can then use `delete` to remove the `length` property.

Answer (score 17):

This is mine implementation of object rotation

```
    function reverseObject(object) {
        var newObject = {};
        var keys = [];

        for (var key in object) {
            keys.push(key);
        }

        for (var i = keys.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          var value = object[keys[i]];
          newObject[keys[i]]= value;
        }       

        return newObject;
      }
```

Comment: nice job , simple for understand.

Comment: I believe the `for...in` in `for (var key in object) {` doesn't guarantee order, so you might not get perfect rotation.

Answer (score 2):

There is no point of doing this, cause object's properties do not have order. Properties order in objects is not guaranteed in JavaScript;

Since ECMAScript 2015, using the Map object could be an alternative. A Map shares some similarities with an Object and [guarantees the keys order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Objects_and_maps_compared):

Comment: Objetcs do have an order, which is set by the order in which elements were defined

Answer (score -2):

```
var reverseObj = function(object) {
    var NewObj = {}, keysArr = Object.keys(object);
    for (var i = keysArr.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        NewObj[keysArr[i]] = object[keysArr[i]];
    }
    return NewObj;
}
```

Comment: Add some comments to your code

Comment: Not working....