# invert snapshot object - Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Object.assign(...).reverse is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to reverse an object, and I try this:

```
        promises.push(
            post.once('value').then((snapshot2) => Object.assign(snapshot2.val(), { key: snapshot2.key }).reverse()
        ));
```

The problem is it gives me this error: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Object.assign(...).reverse is not a function

any ideas how to solve?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Object.assign() returns an Object, which does not have a reverse function.
You could probably do something like this - [How to reverse an object in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36958870/how-to-reverse-an-object-in-javascript)