# How do I reverse the sequence of an object with numeric keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Suppose there is an object in a JavaScript

```
let object = {
    "1": {"SUBJECT": "APPLE"},
    "2": {"SUBJECT": "BANANA"}
};
```

Which is equivalent to a dictionary in Python. Now if I wanted this: -

```
object2 = {
    "2": {"SUBJECT": "BANANA"},
    "1": {"SUBJECT": "APPLE"}
}
```

How do I get it?

Comment: Relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Comment: Does object properties have "order"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to turn an object with keys as indexes into an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36958870/how-to-turn-an-object-with-keys-as-indexes-into-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: @Pipe see the link from evolutionxbox - the short answer is "sort of yes" but it's also a bad idea to rely on it.

Comment: Not really @ThibaultWalterspieler I wanna reverse the entire object... Not just get the array... Thanks though

Comment: I do have a sketchy approach though... Take the Keys in an array, Take the values in another array... Reverse both arrays and POOF! Join them... How does that sound? (I know... pretty naive)

Comment: @BroteenDas that would do nothing. Object keys *that are integers* will be sorted first and will be in ascending order. You cannot override that. You either need a different data structure (a Map will always preserve insertion order) or keep a list of the keys in the array, sort that as you wish and then walk through the array fetching the corresponding value from the object.

Comment: Related: [Does ES6 introduce a well-defined order of enumeration for object properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30076219)

Comment: It doesn't work... It gets sorted back again... Idk how to prevent that...

Comment: @BroteenDas "*It gets sorted back again*" -> "*Object keys that are integers will be sorted first and will be in ascending order. You cannot override that.*"

Comment: Hi, perhaps you could elaborate a bit on what 'reversing the order' of a JS object actually means and how the new structure (assuming it's possible to get it, which I suspect not) is to be used? There may be a better, more reliable way of getting what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out... I just stored the `Object.keys(object)` in a list... reversed it and then iterated through the keys to get the object values... that was hella easy than I thought it would be... but thanks anyway to all of you who responded, interacted or even clicked on my question...

`*sends love online*`